# Heavy Light Decomposition Issue

Tags: algorithm, tree, depth-first-search

I'm studying about HLD and I found out that I need 4 things:

- Given a node, know its chain;
- Given a node, know its position in its chain;
- Given a chain, know the head of it;
- Given a chain, know the length of it.

I was able to do 3 of this 4 things, but I couldn't do the second one.

I did it using a single dfs on the tree, and **I would like to know if (and how) it's possible to add in my code something to solve the second problem**.

Here is the code:

```
#define maxn 1010

int SizeOf[maxn], SpecialChildOf[maxn],
    ChainOf[maxn], SizeOfChain[maxn], HeadOfChain[maxn];
int chain = 0;
vector<int> T[maxn];

void dfs(int u){
    SizeOf[u] = 1;
    int adj = T[u].size();
    if(!adj){
        ChainOf[u] = chain;
        SpecialChildOf[u] = -1;
        HeadOfChain[chain] = u;
        SizeOfChain[chain]++;
        return;
    }
    dfs(T[u][0]);
    int specialChild = T[u][0];
    SizeOf[u] += SizeOf[specialChild];

    for(int i = 1; i < adj; i++){
        int v = T[u][i];
        chain++;
        dfs(v);
        if(SizeOf[v] > SizeOf[specialChild]) specialChild = v;
        SizeOf[u] += SizeOf[v];
    }

    SpecialChildOf[u] = specialChild;
    ChainOf[u] = ChainOf[specialChild];
    SizeOfChain[ChainOf[u]]++;
    HeadOfChain[ChainOf[u]] = u;
}
```

What does it do? It's a simple dfs, you start with chain 0 and follow all the way down the tree without changing the current chain. When you get to a leaf node, you assign that this node is the last element of the current chain (and increase size of current chain by 1) and go back to previous node. When you get back, you see the other children of the node, passing to each one a different chain, and after getting back from all of them, the chain of the son with biggest size between all becomes the chain of current node, and then it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to store the distance to the end of the chain by adding code to just before the return statements:

```
DistanceToEnd[u] = SizeOfChain[ChainOf[u]];
```

After your depth first search has completed, you are then able to compute the position in the chain by something like:

```
distanceToStart = SizeOfChain[ChainOf[u]] - DistanceToEnd[u];
```

Comment: i had thought about this, but isnt there some way to calculate it within the dfs without doing it after its finished?

Comment: Not sure about that, however, do note that you don't need to do a separate pass to compute distanceToStart for every node, just whenever you wish to use distanceToStart you can perform the calculation.